# How can I get Apache working (complains about logfiles) on Ubuntu after a distribution upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I upgraded from Raring to Saucy, and it says it can't open listening sockets:

```
root@ip-10-250-42-219:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# apache2ctl restart
[Tue Oct 22 13:34:05.187996 2013] [core:warn] [pid 1925] AH00117: Ignoring deprecated use of DefaultType in line 174 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.
httpd not running, trying to start
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How can I correct this? Nothing is listening on port 80.

And I checked the log directory `/var/log/apache2` remains available.

--EDIT--

After commenting out `DefaultType`, I tried to restart and got a somewhat simpler error message:

```
httpd not running, trying to start
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

My `apache2.conf` is below. It doesn't tell the whole story, as it doesn't include e.g. the `sites-enabled` directory contents, but here it is:

```
#
# Based upon the NCSA server configuration files originally by Rob McCool.
#
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# The configuration directives are grouped into three basic sections:
#  1. Directives that control the operation of the Apache server process as a
#     whole (the 'global environment').
#  2. Directives that define the parameters of the 'main' or 'default' server,
#     which responds to requests that aren't handled by a virtual host.
#     These directives also provide default values for the settings
#     of all virtual hosts.
#  3. Settings for virtual hosts, which allow Web requests to be sent to
#     different IP addresses or hostnames and have them handled by the
#     same Apache server process.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/etc/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "/etc/apache2/foo.log".
#

### Section 1: Global Environment
#
# The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
# such as the number of concurrent requests it can handle or where it
# can find its configuration files.
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
# LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
#              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
#              and starting Apache.
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
#DefaultType text/plain


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
# Include httpd.conf

# Include ports listing
#Include ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
#Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

Comment: Are you user that another server isn't listening to the configured port or otherwise you have configured a port/interface not available (ie you have configured to use ip:port but ip is not registered in the system).

Comment: It's the same system as I had working before, with the IP I had working before. The sites are all registered to '<VirtualHost *:80>'

Comment: _Does_ the apache error log have more information as suggested by the error message?

Comment: error.log is a 0 byte file. error.log.1 last records the SIGTERM sent by the upgrade. (I'm not sure how "Unable to open logs" suggests "More information is availble in the logfiles.")

Answer (score 1):

#### Idea #1

I would start with debugging your configuration file and specifically this error message that you're getting:

> [Tue Oct 22 13:34:05.187996 2013] [core:warn] [pid 1925] AH00117: Ignoring deprecated use of DefaultType in line 174 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

Specifically look at line # 74 of the file, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. You likely have either an configuration option that's likely been either deprecated or the values that it takes have changed and you're giving it an invalid value.

#### Idea #2

The error message during startup:

> no listening sockets available, shutting down

To see if something really is using port 80 we can try 2 things.

1. Run `netstat`

   ```
   $ netstat -tan | grep :80
   tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      
   tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.105:80     ::ffff:192.168.1.6:40435    TIME_WAIT
   ```
2. Change Apache's listening port to 33333

   In file `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` change this:

   ```
   Listen 80
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   Listen 33333
   ```

Comment: Thank you; I've edited my post to include some further information.

Comment: @JonathanHayward - I think we're getting warmer. This line "AH00015: Unable to open logs" means 1 of 2 things. Permissions issue in writing the log files out or you've run out of disk space where the logs are kept.

Comment: The disk is 88% full. I just set /var/log/apache2 and descendants to mode 777 and restarted, and saw the same behavior.

Comment: @JonathanHayward - the other thing to consider is that it may be something to do with apparmor. You could try temporarily disabling it.

Comment: Thank you; I've turned apparmor and the error message is the same.

Comment: @JonathanHayward - how did you confirm that it was not already running on port 80?

Comment: telnet localhost 80

Comment: @JonathanHayward - would you mind double checking with this command instead: `netstat -tan|grep :80`?

Comment: @JonathanHayward - see updates.

Answer (score 0):

I encoutred the same problem in my server this morning:

> AH00015: Unable to open logs

I managed to allow all rights in security tab on the logs folder for the user who run the apache service, this resolved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

no listening sockets available, shutting down this errors show you to some of your app using the port 80
i have no idea how to check which app uses port 80 but u can change the localhost port from apache httpd.conf
settting might be like this

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

you change the listen port like 8080 and start using from http://localhost:8080